# Why is my total multiplier adding a pattern of 2 to each answer?

Tags: javascript

```js
function getTotal() {
  let total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let valueToAdd = i;
    var multiplier = 2;
    total += valueToAdd * multiplier;
    console.log(total);
  }

  return total;
}
console.log(
  getTotal()
);
```

It was my estimation, that at each iteration of the loop, the total should be:

a) 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... etc

but instead, I am getting the following answers: b) 0,2,6,12,20,30,42..... 90

Where in my code is the pattern of this ensuing addition being replicated?

Why am I not getting the original answer I intended in a)?

Comment: You're increasing `valueToAdd` on each iteration. Remove it entirely, and use `total += multiplier;`?

Comment: With `total += valueToAdd * multiplier;` You are printing `2, 2+4, 2+4+6, 2+4+6+8, 2+4+6+8+10`. You probably want `total = valueToAdd * multiplier;` instead

Comment: I always thought that += was a shorthand for assigning a value to my variable without actually adding any arithmetic or numbers.

Comment: @ironSteel but that's what `=` does. As in `a = 1` would always result in assigning the value `1`. The `a += 1` is a shorthand to `a = a + 1`. In general if you have an operator and equals, it's a shorthand for "take the current value, do the operation with the right hand of the equals and assign back to the variable", for example `a *= 2` is `a = a * 2` and `a /= 2` is `a = a / 2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `total = valueToAdd * multiplier;` instead of adding the result of each iteration to `total` to get that output you expect.

```js
function getTotal() {
  let total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let valueToAdd = i;
    var multiplier = 2;
    total = valueToAdd * multiplier;
    console.log(total);
  }

  return total;
}

console.log(getTotal());
```

Also note that it returns `0`, to avoid that you can start your iteration with `i=1` and condition as `i<=10`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding and multiplying both by using this

```
total += valueToAdd * multiplier;
```

So, If you want to implement by multiplying, you should be doing

```
    total = valueToAdd * multiplier;
```

but if you want to implement by adding, you should be doing

```
total += multiplier;
```

Answer (score 0):

On third iteration 
 `total += valueToAdd * multiplier`
Translates to
`2 += 2 * 2`

With your intended result your code should be
`total = valueToAdd * multiplier`

So each iteration value of `total` will be overriden by the formula
While the current one appends the result of formula to variable total, in this case (integer data type) will be summed

Answer (score 0):

Due to my low reputation ( < 50 ), I can't add comment. So I make it a new answer.

total += valueToAdd * multiplier; is the same as 「total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier;」

because total, valueToAdd and multiplier are all numbers, the + operator will do arithmetic addition.So

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = 0 + 0 * 2 = 0 ( when i = 0 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = 0 + 1 * 2 = 2 ( when i = 1 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = 2 + 2 * 2 = 6 ( when i = 2 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = 6 + 3 * 2 = 12 ( when i = 3 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = 12 + 4 * 2 = 20 ( when i = 4 )

that's why you get 0,2,6,12,20...

But if we change the line 「let total = 0;」 to 「let total = '0';」. Now the + operator will be used to concatenate (add) strings

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = '0' + 0 * 2 = '0' + 0 = '00' ( when i = 0 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = '00' + 1 * 2 = '00' + 2 = '002' ( when i = 1 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = '002' + 2 * 2 = '002' + 4 = '0024' ( when i = 2 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = '0024' + 3 * 2 = '0024' + 6 = '00246' ( when i = 3 )

total = total + valueToAdd * multiplier = '00246' + 4 * 2 = '002468' ( when i = 4 )

you'll get the final string '002468...18' as the result.

If this is what you want, and you want the string stars from '2'. Do the following modification

1. let total = ''; // an empty string
2. for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) { // i starts from 1

and you will get '24681012141618'.